# How to extract bytes from the UInt128 type

Tags: c#, packetdotnet

The PacketDotNet library defines a struct [`UInt128`](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/blob/e1cfa913429de61676820d39da92c8af0603b6ea/PcapDotNet/src/PcapDotNet.Base/UInt128.cs). See:

How to convert this type into a simple byte array in C#?

Comment: If you are simply including the source (instead of using the whole library), simply modify from `private` to `public` its readonly fields

Comment: I'm the author of PacketDotNet. Any suggestions for improving this would be welcome, feel free to open an issue on the GitHub repo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be cast to a `BigTnteger` then call `ToByteArray()` as below.

```
var number = new Uint128();

((BigInteger)number).ToByteArray();
```

Comment: Note that `((BigInteger)UInt128.MaxValue).ToByteArray().Length == 17`. An extra byte is added for the sign.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you assign it to a `BigInteger` variable and use the `ToByteArray()` method on that.

```
UInt128 n128 = 12345;
BigInteger bi = (BigInteger)n128;
byte[] ba = bi.ToByteArray();
```

Comment: Note that `((BigInteger)UInt128.MaxValue).ToByteArray().Length == 17`. An extra byte is added for the sign.

Answer (score 2):

I've also discovered myself another possibility:

```
public static unsafe byte[] GetBytesFromUInt128(this UInt128 value)
{
    byte[] numArray = new byte[16];
    fixed (byte* numPtr = numArray)
        *(UInt128*) numPtr = value;
    return numArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some funny tricks that you can do with newer .net core:

```
var ui = UInt128.MaxValue - 1;

{
    var span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<UInt128, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref ui, 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < UInt128.SizeOf; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(span[i]);
    }
}
```

and/or given

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct UInt128Split
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public UInt128 UInt128;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ulong ULong1;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public ulong ULong2;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint UInt1;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public uint UInt2;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public uint UInt3;

    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public uint UInt4;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte Byte1;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte Byte2;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte Byte3;

    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte Byte4;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public byte Byte5;

    [FieldOffset(5)]
    public byte Byte6;

    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public byte Byte7;

    [FieldOffset(7)]
    public byte Byte8;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public byte Byte9;

    [FieldOffset(9)]
    public byte Byte10;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public byte Byte11;

    [FieldOffset(11)]
    public byte Byte12;

    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public byte Byte13;

    [FieldOffset(13)]
    public byte Byte14;

    [FieldOffset(14)]
    public byte Byte15;

    [FieldOffset(15)]
    public byte Byte16;
}
```

then

```
var ui = UInt128.MaxValue - 1;

{
    ref UInt128Split rf = ref Unsafe.As<UInt128, UInt128Split>(ref ui);

    Console.WriteLine(rf.UInt1);
    Console.WriteLine(rf.UInt2);
    Console.WriteLine(rf.UInt3);
    Console.WriteLine(rf.UInt4);

    Console.WriteLine(rf.ULong1);
    Console.WriteLine(rf.ULong2);

    // rf is the same as ui, so if we modify rf we modify ui!
    Console.WriteLine(ui);
    rf.ULong1 -= 11454;
    Console.WriteLine(ui);
}
```

Comment: Could you update the answer as UInt128.SizeOf, doesn't work now.  Uint does not contain a definition for 'SizeOf'.

Comment: @ScottJibben Seems strange, it still exists in the github sourcecode: https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/blob/e1cfa913429de61676820d39da92c8af0603b6ea/PcapDotNet/src/PcapDotNet.Base/UInt128.cs#L17

Comment: @ScottJibben Found. The poster of the question asked about the `UInt128` defined in a specific library. .NET 7 and 8 define "their" version of [`System.UInt128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint128?view=net-7.0) . Try something like `UInt128 ui = 0; var binint = (IBinaryInteger<UInt128>)ui; int size = binint.GetByteCount(); var bytes = new byte[size]; binint.WriteLittleEndian(bytes);`

Answer (score 0):

Using System.UInt128 (.NET 7).  May not be relevant to PacketDotNet.UInt128.

This is similar to other solutions but includes a flag for unsigned values.  This shouldn't add the extra 17th byte that @xanatos is referring to:

```
UInt128 number = UInt128.Parse("338288524927261089654164245681446711638");
byte[] myBytes = ((BigInteger)number).ToByteArray(isUnsigned: true);
```